# How to prevent Errbit from merging general uncaught exceptions thrown from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, errbit

I am trying to use errbit (https://github.com/errbit/errbit/) for tracking our exceptions in a .NET application. To integrate our application with errbit, we used SharpBrake (https://github.com/MikeRalphson/SharpBrake).

Within the global.asax file, I catch uncaught exceptions and forward them to errbit.

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception lastError = Server.GetLastError();
    lastError.SendToAirbrake();
    Server.ClearError();
}
```

As a test, I threw an exception within one page:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException()
```

And then I threw another exception from another page:

```
throw new Exception()
```

When I went to errbit, I expected the errors show up as separate errors for my test application, however, for some reason those exceptions are grouped together as the same.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong or how to modify the merge mechanism within errbit?

Comment: Can you show us what are in your problem view on errbit ?

Answer (score 1):

The merging system on Errbit take information about :

```
{
  :file_or_message => file_or_message,
  :error_class => notice.error_class,
  :component => notice.component || 'unknown',
  :action => notice.action,
  :environment => notice.environment_name || 'development',
  :api_key => api_key
}
```

You can see the strategy on the fingerprint class : https://github.com/errbit/errbit/blob/master/app/models/fingerprint.rb

You can "unmerge" you problem if you want by select your problem and click on button "unmerge"